# Allow just one PHPSESSID per user

Tags: php, security

I've created a webservice, on which users can log in sending an oauth token. As response, this webservice returns a PHPSESSID cookie to keep the user logged in.

However, if you do log in several times, a new ID is generated each time. Examples:

1. ts1i3plmdcnmoivai637a27oe1
2. bhn1snms8kajmpo8ape5e5ctj3
3. d5467idr1ree9dcq6h9cqt9oj2
4. en2vbo1r62fqmrriid8l4rkvd3

All those 4 ID's are valid.

**Is there any way make this sessid unique per user?** So for example, when ID#4 is generated, previous 3 are discarded. Then I could handle a 403 error or whatever.

On the other hand, a second question:

**Is it possible to make this PHPSESSID token longer?**

Comment: Keep track of the issued session IDs, then you can revoke one if a user account has more than one session assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that then it's better to use your own cookies instead of php sessions.

You'll need to generate a random cookie key when someone log in, I'll call that random cookie key as cookie_id.

Then you need to store it in the database with the user_id it's connected to, so you can make a new table in database called sessions, with cookie_id and user_id fields (user_id needs to be unique), or you can extend your user table with cookies_id field.

After saving the cookie_id value with it's related user in db, you'll give that cookie_id to that user through cookies.

You can verify logged-in user with his cookie_id.
When logging out cookie_id will be null in db.
When another login happen, new cookie_id will be written over the old cookie_id  in db.
That's it

---

Also You can set the period of your cookie with the expire parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

For more security you can make cronjobs to delete cookie ids from db after some period of time. (You'll need to store the login date to do so)

Comment: I accept it, as it pointed to my final answer. I'm using symfony2, so I've to handle it. Read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html